# Custom Binary Input - Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am developing a demo application in Hadoop and my input is .mrc image files. I want to load them to hadoop and do some image processing over them.

These are binary files that contain a large header with metadata followed by the data of a set of images. The information on how to read the images is also contained in the header (eg. number_of_images, number_of_pixels_x, number_of_pixels_y, bytes_per_pixel, so after the header bytes, the first `[number_of_pixels_x*number_of_pixels_y*bytes_per_pixel]` are the first image, then the second and so on].

What is a good Input format for these kinds of files? I thought two possible solutions:

1. Convert them to sequence files by placing the metadata in the sequence file header and have  pairs for each image. In this case can I access the metadata from all mappers?
2. Write a custom InputFormat and RecordReader and create splits for each image while placing the metadata in distributed cache.

I am new in Hadoop, so I may be missing something. Which approach you think is better? is any other way that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your file formats, the first option seems to be the better option. Using sequence files you can leverage a lot of SequenceFile related tools to get better performance. However, there are two things that do concern me with this approach.

1. How will you get your .mrc files into a .seq format?
2. You mentioned that the header is large, this may reduce the performance of SequenceFiles

But even with those concerns, I think that representing your data in SequenceFile's is the best option.

Comment: The header is 129KB always. Is that too large?

Comment: If the header is that small you're probably fine. When you said large header, I was thinking it was in the order of several MBs