# Read image in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

How to convert an image to ***sequence file* format in hadoop?**. I dont want to read a bunch of files, just a single image and manipulate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Binary Input - Hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465373/custom-binary-input-hadoop)

Comment: Another related link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754154/hadoop-example-process-to-generating-a-sequencefile-with-image-binaries-to-be-p

Comment: If these don't help, you need to provide more detail in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The code from [HIPI's](https://github.com/uvagfx/hipi) [SeqImageBundle](https://github.com/uvagfx/hipi/blob/release/src/hipi/imagebundle/SeqImageBundle.java) demonstrates how to write a collection of images to a single SequenceFile.